# php5 pagination current page

Tags: php, html, css, pagination

I am trying to highlight the current page in my website using the class `active` so that users can know which page the users can know which page they are currently in. Below is the php5 code I am trying to get to work.

```
<!-- Pagination -->
<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
  <?php for ($page=1; $page<=$number_of_pages; $page++) { ?> 
  <li><a href="page.php?page=<?php echo $page?>" class= "active" ><?php echo $page ?></a></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

This is what I am trying to obtain

[image: This is what I am trying to obtain]

But, this is what my code currently generates

[image: This is what my code currently generates]

This is the best I could come up with

```
  <?php for ($page=1; $page<=$number_of_pages; $page++) { ?> 
      <li><a href="page.php?page=<?php echo $page?>"  <?php if ($_GET['page'] == $page) { echo 'class= "active"'; } ?> >
  <?php echo $page ?></a></li> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Because php doesn't know which is the current page so it puts the class in whole loop elements

Comment: You are adding the class `active1` to tab 1, and `active2` to tab 2. Always. There is no difference between active and inactive tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Try This ,where set `$current_page` to your current page.

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
    <?php
    $current_page = 1;
    for ($page = 1; $page <= $number_of_pages; $page++) {
        ?> 
        <li><a href="page.php?page=<?php echo $page ?>" class= "<?php if ($page == $current_page) echo 'active'; ?>"><?php echo $page ?></a></li>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: The code is not working. All the icons still have the same color.

Comment: Technically this is the right approach. But you still need to add styling, like `.active{ background-color: white; }`, otherwise you won't see the difference.